# HTTP requests never reach apache2

Tags: http, ubuntu, apache2

I have a weird problem with my apache2 webserver on an ubuntu server 20.04 system. It seems like HTTP request never reach the server, since the access log is empty. I had this problem once before and after some try and error I resolved it (kinda accedentally) by removing [K3S](https://k3s.io/) from my system. This worked for some time, until the hoster, who hosts my virtual server, performed some maintainence tasks and I assume restartet the virtual maschine. Now when I try to reach my server via HTTP I get timeouts and as I already wrote, it looks like the requests never reach the webserver. I can't even access port 80 or 443 on localhost with telnet or curl. Here is some information about my network setup:

*nmap localhost*:

```
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp    open     ssh
80/tcp    filtered http
443/tcp   filtered https
3306/tcp  open     mysql
8080/tcp  open     http-proxy
8081/tcp  open     blackice-icecap
8200/tcp  open     trivnet1
8443/tcp  open     https-alt
10000/tcp open     snet-sensor-mgmt
50000/tcp open     ibm-db2
```

*netstat -tulpn*:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1412/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      619/apache2
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      420/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      560/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8761            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      440/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8762            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      452/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      619/apache2
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      487/containerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9990          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      609/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2251/vault
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      476/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      863/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::50000                :::*                    LISTEN      1055/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1010/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      560/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      863/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      1082/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      1068/docker-proxy
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           1412/perl
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           420/systemd-resolve
```

*iptables -L -n*:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.42.0.0/16
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 ctstate ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:5000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:2376
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:2375

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000
DROP       all  -- !127.0.0.0/8          127.0.0.0/8          /* block incoming localnet connections */ ! ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT

Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule */ ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-PROXY-CANARY (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain KUBE-SERVICES (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.43.54.73          /* kube-system/metrics-server has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:443 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.43.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:metrics has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:9153 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.43.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints */ udp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.43.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:53 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I am really not that knowledgeable on network stuff, but I guess there are still some leftover configurations from K3S, since I likely failed to probably remove the kubernetes distribution from my system. As you can see there are some suspicious *KUBE-* filters left, when listing the iptables rules.

Does anyone have a clue how to resolve this?

**>>Update<<**

It seems like only apache2 is listening to port 80 and 443, as `sudo ss -ltnp` gives me this result:

```
State                         Recv-Q                         Send-Q                                                 Local Address:Port                                                  Peer Address:Port                        Process
LISTEN                        0                              511                                                          0.0.0.0:80                                                         0.0.0.0:*                            users:(("apache2",pid=465645,fd=3),("apache2",pid=465644,fd=3),("apache2",pid=212318,fd=3))
LISTEN                        0                              511                                                          0.0.0.0:443                                                        0.0.0.0:*                            users:(("apache2",pid=465645,fd=4),("apache2",pid=465644,fd=4),("apache2",pid=212318,fd=4))
```

Maybe some firewall is blocking the access? I already disabled ufw and the port is also open via iptables.

Also something I have noticed, I get the following when executing nmap localhost:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-20 19:55 CET
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 127.0.0.1, 16) => Invalid argument
Offending packet: TCP 127.0.0.1:54146 > 127.0.0.1:443 S ttl=56 id=15766 iplen=44  seq=1065797325 win=1024 
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 127.0.0.1, 16) => Invalid argument
Offending packet: TCP 127.0.0.1:54146 > 127.0.0.1:80 S ttl=55 id=5390 iplen=44  seq=1065797325 win=1024 
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 127.0.0.1, 16) => Invalid argument
Offending packet: TCP 127.0.0.1:54147 > 127.0.0.1:80 S ttl=54 id=43682 iplen=44  seq=1065862860 win=1024 
sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(4, packet, 44, 0, 127.0.0.1, 16) => Invalid argument
Offending packet: TCP 127.0.0.1:54147 > 127.0.0.1:443 S ttl=41 id=63761 iplen=44  seq=1065862860 win=1024
```

Answer (score 0):

In access log a message is reported once apache2 is responding to the request.

If apache2 is not responding to the request due to failure. There is no message in access log.

From your post it seems that ports 80(http) and 443 (https) are open. But not sure by whom. Make sure you know which port apache2 is listening on.

1. Use `curl -v` command to test apache2 on local machine use ip address with designated apache2 port.
2. Use `curl -v` command to test apache2 on local machine use FQDN/DNS name with designated apache2 port.
3. Use `curl -v` command to test apache2 from remote machine use ip address with designated apache2 port.
4. Use `telnet` or `netcat` to test apache2 connection on designated apache2 port.
   .

Comment: I can't access port 80 and 443, neither on the local machine nor on a remote machine, but other ports like 8080 do work fine. I tried both curl and telnet with my servers IP, the DNS name and even localhost to no avail. My suspicion is, that some other application blocks my ports, but I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Please consult with this article: https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/ . I use the following command to find port and PID association: `sudo ss -ltnp`

Comment: I edited my post, seems like apache2 is listening to port 80 and 443.